# How long will spaghetti last in the refrigerator when stored in a sealed container?

Tags: sauce, storage-lifetime, refrigerator, spaghetti

How long will spaghetti with sauce containing diced tomatoes last in the refrigerator when stored in a sealed container?

Comment: No time at all, from a taste and quality point of view. The linked question covers "won't kill you" but not "things that are just better not done" and refrigerating spaghetti is one of those things. It won't kill you, but it will never be as good as when freshly cooked. Save the sauce, and cook only as much spaghetti as you'll actually eat, ideally.